# template inheritance with Express and Jade

Tags: templates, node.js, express, pug

I'm having difficulty getting template inheritance to work properly. I'm finding that I can get index/layout working well, but that it's not including other extended blocks. For example, here's my layout.jade file:

```
#wrapper
      block tester

      // Side bar
      #list
        ul#friend-list.browser
          li#friends.label Friends
          li#following.label Following

      // Content
      block content
```

In the same directory I have index.jade and tester.jade. index.jade contains the following, and works:

```
extends layout

block content
  .content
        .row-fluid
          .span12
            .row-fluid
              #browser-toolbar.span12.toolbar
            .row-fluid
              .span12
                #bento
```

tester.jade looks like this, and *doesn't* work:

```
extend layout

block tester
  h1 hello world
```

I'm currently using Express v.3.0b4. Can anyone help explain why this isn't working? It doesn't throw an error -- it just doesn't render the tester.jade file at all.

Answer (score 1):

Is it just a matter of using `extends` with an 's' vs `extend`?

Comment: Good catch, but this didn't turn out to be the problem. I think I had the concept of 'extend' a little backwards. Using your route, you call up something like 'index' which then extends 'layout'. But other files that have also extended 'layout' aren't called, so they don't render. It makes sense. To achieve something like I wanted before, I can use 'include' statements.

Comment: You should answer your own question with this

Answer (score 0):

Express 3.x significantly changed view handling and no longer automatically references a layout. Check the migration guide.